# In Australia if you are working from home and your employer is based in another state which public holiday do you get?

Tags: australia, employment

In Australia the states have their public holidays on different days. If an organisation has offices in many states the staff get the day off for the state they are based in. However if the organisation is based in one state and the person working from home is based in another state which public holiday should be taken?

Comment: FYI some states also have regional public holidays.

Answer (score 1):

> **Working outside your state or region on a public holiday**
>
> An employee is entitled to public holidays depending on where they are based for work not where they are working on the day of the public holiday

[Fair Work Ombudsman](https://www.fairwork.gov.au/leave/public-holidays)

Comment: Right now I’m working from home but my company has an office (quite empty right now) where I used to work. So wher am I “based for work”?

Comment: @gnasher729 at that office